# is delete called on a c++ default pointer parameter

Tags: c++

I have a function that instantiates a pointer by default if it is not supplied with the second parameter.

```
void doSomething(int a, Obj* obj = new Obj()) {
...
}
```

Do I need to call an explicit delete inside the function if I want to release obj or it is done automatically if I had instantiated the pointer from the default param values?

I want to avoid doing an explicit delete myself since if the second argument is passed then I don't want to delete the pointer passed by the caller.

Comment: `delete` is never called by the language.  Consider a smart pointer based parameter that reference counts (otherwise you'll never be sure if the object was constructed as a default parameter)

Comment: *"I want to avoid doing an explicit delete myself since if the second argument is passed then I don't want to delete the pointer passed by the caller."* Right. Which is why you cannot use this pattern.

Comment: this seems like an opportunity to simply have a `doSomething(int a)` overload that calls `doSomething(int a, Obj* obj)` with an obj pointer that *it* manages. Or better, a smart pointer. Also consider: what happens if someone explicitly passes a null pointer into your function at present? It seems like you might be trying to guarantee for the function that `obj` is never null, but this is a bad way to do that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your memory ownership semantics need a rework. In some cases you own the memory and others you don't. If you insist on default creating an instance of `Obj`, then also accept a boolean that indicates whether you own the memory or not. In the end, though, I actually suggest you use overloading instead to accomplish this, where one function takes one argument and the other two. The one that only accepts one will create an instance of `Obj` and then call your base `doSomething` function.

Something like:

```
void doSomething(int a, Obj* obj) {
...
}

void doSomething(int a) {
   Obj tmp;
   doSomething(a, &tmp);
}
```